# datatables lock thead like freeze rows in excel

Tags: datatables

Is it possible to "lock" the top row of the results from dataTables? so that when i scroll through 100s of row results, the top heading doesnt move. I have tried setting a size to tbody and making it overflow in css but that obviously doesn't work.

```
tbody{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:600px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  Sounds like you want to use the DataTables "FixedHeader" extension:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table );
} );
```

Source: https://www.datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/